# Is there any size limitations on 3d files loaded using ARKit?

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit

I am developing an augmented reality app using ARKit in which we needs to load a 3d model of a group of buildings. What I am planning is to detect a horizontal plane and place the object there. Is there any size limitations on the 3d model or size of plane detected?

Comment: Size in terms of physical size or the file size of your model? Detected ARKit planes aren't usually bigger than a few square meters but that does not limit you from placing larger models on top of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about physical size of a file, I should say that a number of polygons per model is much more important than a size in MB. Try to create models containing 5K to 10K poly faces per model.

If you are talking about size of a 3D building itself, remember that for large environments you need to set up Z Clipping's `Far` property what is a far clipping plane of camera's frustum. Default value is 100 meters. And be ready to have rendering depth artifacts for long-distance objects.

Hope this helps.